# Can i deploy react app with back end node and mongodb on a local area network?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mongodb, lan

I was building frontend react and backend node and MongoDB web app clinic management system for a clinic since it is a web app it requires internet but we don't have good internet connection so my question is how can I deploy that exact application in local area network what kind of hardware do I need?

Comment: By local area means, do you want it to be accessible over a closed network, or for anyone on the internet to use it?

Comment: in a closed network, only in the clinic but the clinic has 5 departments and they have to synced

Comment: I wouldn't worry about the hardware being good enough until I saw everything else working.  There are too many other things that can go wrong, and change everything.  I would start by trying to serve it on my laptop, or an old PC lying around.  Working out all the networking, certs, lan address, hostname.. if everybody is on the same network.. sounds like the hard part.

Comment: I think it's possible to do this one. If each computer could ping to a main computer (which is installed mongoDb, React App, ...) then you only need to change the host file of client computer and point to the local ip address of the main computer.